# How to check if JBoss is running on Unix server?

Tags: linux, unix, service, process, jboss

I have a script below that I'd like to echo out "jboss not running" or "jboss is running" depending on whether it can find the jboss process in the process list. However, when I shut down Jboss it still executes the Else condition and says "jboss is running". If I manually do "pgrep -f jboss" it doesn't return anything, so why is it still going into the Else condition? *puzzled*

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -z "$(pgrep -f jboss)" ]
  then
  echo "jboss is not running"
else
  echo "jboss is running"
fi
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 17):

Instead of checking the output, just use the command:

```
if pgrep -f jboss >/dev/null
  then
  echo "jboss is running"
else
  echo "jboss is not running"
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Get the process ID JBoss 7 / EAP 6:

```
pgrep -f org.jboss.as
```

So if you want to enhance the former example script with this:

```
if [ -z "$(pgrep -f org.jboss.as)" ]
then 
 echo "JBoss is NOT running"
else
  echo "JBoss is running"
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `exit status` of the command -

```
#!/bin/bash

pgrep -f jboss &> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then
  echo "jboss is running"
else
  echo "jboss is not running"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

**This is the best way:**

```
if [ -z "$(ps -ef | grep java | grep jboss)" ]
then 
 echo "JBoss is NOT running"
else
  echo "JBoss is running"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#! /bin/bash
 if [ -z "$(ps -ef | grep org.jboss.Main)" ]
then 
 echo "jboss is not running"
else
  echo "jboss is running"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is use this

```
result=`$jboss/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect controller=localhost:$controller_port --commands=\"read-attribute server-state\" > out 2&1`
echo "$result" | grep -q "running"
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then 
   echo "Jboss running"
fi
```

If you want to check if ear or war file is deployed then you could use the following command

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss\-cli.sh --connect controller=localhost:$PORT  --command="deployment-info --name=$YOUR_WAR_OR_EAR_FILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Run **jps**, **grep** it for the line with you jboss, **cut** the **PID** from the line and check the PID.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below function in bash script; below function return PID of Jboss if Jboss is started yet. notice that $1 is base directory of your jboss. for example:
$1=/root/app/wildfly-X.Final

```
function getJbossPID() {
local pid;
local DIR=$1;
if [[ ! -z $DIR ]]; then
    local result=();
    jps=`jps -m`
    if [[ ! -z $jps ]]; then
        IFS='
        '
        jps_result=`jps -m`
        for jps_line_result in $jps_result; do
            result_jps=$jps_line_result;
            if [[ $result_jps == *$DIR* ]]; then
                unset IFS
                array=( $result_jps );
                pid=${array[0]};
            fi
        IFS='
        '
        done;
        unset IFS;
    fi
fi
echo $pid;
}
```

you can use above function same as below:

> PID=$(getJbossPID $YOUR_JBOSS)

Answer (score -2):

You cant check the jboss in that way.
Because Jboss started sometimes log time like 1-2 minutes.
So your script shows only process Jboss, not the "Jboss is really UP" (I mean application on JBoss).

Comment: You haven't answered his question; you just explained why his check isn't good enough to monitor jboss.