# How to start JBoss from Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jboss

Does someone know how start JBoss from Jenkins before deployment?
I need to check if Jboss is running before deployment.

I will be grateful if someone helps with this issue!

Well,

I have tried to follow the advice from **Gerold Broser**.

So, I have installed JBoss management plugin and conditional build step plugin.

After that in Manage Jenkins/Configure System/JBoss Managment Builder - I have added a remote server.

And in Project/Configure/Build/Add build step/Conditional step (single) - I have tried:

**Run?** Boolean condition

**Token** pgrep -f jboss < /dev/null

**On evaluation failure** Don't run

**Builder** Jboss Management

**Operation** - Start.

Save/Apply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [JBoss Management Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JBoss+Management+Plugin):

> This plugin allows to manage a JBoss Application Server during build procedure.
>
> With the plugin we can start/stop JBoss AS.

To check whether it's running see [How to check if JBoss is running on Unix server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761374/how-to-check-if-jboss-is-running-on-unix-server) and to deploy conditionally:

- Use the [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin#ConditionalBuildStepPlugin-Conditionalstep%28single%29) and add the script variant of your choice to:

  **Build** → **Conditional step (single)** → Run?   *Execute shell* → Command
- Select **Advanced...** → On evaluation failure:   *Don't Run*
- Select Builder:   *... your deployment build step ...*

Comment: Hello. Gerold Broser!  I have installed the 2 plugins. And I have tried to do the following:                                                                                                                Run?: boolean condition, token - pgrep -f jboss </dev/null;                                         On evaluation failure: Don't run;                                                                         Builder: Jboss Management, Operation - Start.                                                But the server is not turned on. What I have mistaken here?

Comment: @user5455130 Can you please update your question with what you have tried. It's no fun to read such with the limited formatting options in comments.

Comment: Hi, Gerold Broser. I wrote an answer because I can not format comments well. Please see my answer bellow. Thank you!

Comment: @user5455130 I wrote „_please update your question_“ for a reason. Is there no **edit** link below the tags of your question?

Comment: Gerold Broser, I have edited my question. I hope I finally managed to do it in the correct way. Can you have a look, please! Thank you!