# Run Jboss server using jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I need to start jboss server from jenkins.
For example via command line this command is executed to run a wildfly instance:
stanadalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0.
Is there any way to do the same but using jenkins?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to start JBoss from Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33285494/how-to-start-jboss-from-jenkins)

Comment: I think , the real question is : how execute windows commands from jenkins

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, there are some approaches :

- Simples way is just execute as simple command adding a build step **execute shell**:

[image]

Just put your command **standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0.** in the box.

- Another approach could be use docker and just start your widfly container with **execute shell** step:

  ```
  docker run -d --name my-widfly widfly-docker-image
  ```

Docker image https://gist.github.com/jesty/a0a16fed7909e58e04c6f603e6827578

This approach is better than execute directly standalone.bat

Comment: Thanks, and how can I run the same command over a windows jenkins installation?. Should I put the same command in the command text area?

Comment: Jenkins and widfly are installed in the windows machine ?

Comment: Yes, both tools are installed in windows

Comment: Now how could I run more than one wildfly instance?

Comment: (Hard way) : download another wildfly zip and change the default port and just start it with your `standalone.bat command`. In some case, more than one port must be changed. (Easy way) : Docker

Comment: Ok, and how could I run more than one widlfly instance command in jenkins?, I have the commands.

Comment: I have two configured commands in jenkins but the first command is just executed

Comment: If you have installed 2 widlfly in your server , each of them has its own path **/opt/servers/widlfly-01 and /opt/servers/widlfly-02** as example. So you could create a **choice parameter** called **severName** with **widlfly-01** and **widlfly-02**. After that in your commands use **$serverName** as variable  for locate right **standlone.bat** For example `cd /opt/servers/$serverName && standlone.bat ...`

Comment: Thanks for the tips, now, how could I configure two server instances, the commands are standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.server.base.dir="D:\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone-1 and standalone.bat –b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.server.base.dir="D:\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone-2" -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=200 but first vommand is just executed, I need to configure them in the same server instead of two servers

Comment: uhmmm how you manage the ports if you use the same instance ?

Comment: When I execute both commands manually the next ports are enabled, 8085 and 8285 when executing second command

Comment: So you dont need to change manually the port in wildfly configurations files?

Comment: The first one port is configured with 8085, the second one 8285 is enabled after executing the second command, but I need to execute both commands in jenkins, which has an option to execute multiple windows commands.

Comment: So, this **-Djboss.server.base.dir** is the only parameter that must be change to run several wildfly ?

Comment: Yes, there are two standalone directories inside, standalone-1 and standalone-2

Comment: You could create a choice parameter with options **server1** and **server2**. And do the trick in your script :  https://gist.github.com/jrichardsz/c6ea18e569cc3fac86dc7689568f5e59

Comment: I will check, I have another question, how could I run both standalone commands in CMD?, I tried to execute: standalone.bat -b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.server.base.dir="D:\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone-1" & standalone.bat –b 0.0.0.0 -Djboss.server.base.dir="D:\wildfly-9.0.2.Final\standalone-2" -Djboss.socket.binding.port-offset=200 in one line, but just first command runs

Comment: This conversation is getting too long. If you like, contact me https://jrichardsz.github.io